# How to achieve Font Awesome stack icons feature in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-awesome, react-native-vector-icons

Achieving Stack/Overlap Icons using React native.

I am trying to achieve something like this in react native:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to use custom icons in your project? As describe in https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#custom-fonts ?

Comment: Yes. I am currently using vector icons in my project.  Rather using custom fonts, i am trying to find if i can stack multiple icons to create another icon like the link i mentioned above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was able to achieve like this with react native elements [ not sure if they use zIndex internally]

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'relative',
            height: 64,
            width: 64,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Icon type="font-awesome" name="square" size={64} />
          <Icon
            type="font-awesome"
            name="twitter"
            color="white"
            size={32}
            containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute' }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And the container style would be

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
```

snack repo:

https://snack.expo.io/@roach_iam/vigorous-blueberries

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by doing it like this. Using width and height helps you keep the view in place and aligning everything to the center so it looks nice like stacked icons.[image]

```
<View style={{
        position:"relative",
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:"center",
        width:40,
        height:40
      }}>
         <Icon name="circle" size={34} color={"black"} />
         <Icon name="flag" size={20} color={"white"} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 99}} />  
      </View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/HkxWerHBr

Answer (score 4):

**Output:**

[image]

In this Example I stacked the FontAwesome Icon "square" and "home". To stack them, you need a parent view with `position: 'relative'`. Then you can apply `position: 'absolute'`and a zIndex to the icon which should be on top of the other one. Afterwards you can position the icon for example with the top/left style property.

**Code:**

```
  <View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
         <Icon name="square" size={24} color={"black"} />
         <Icon 
          name="home" 
          size={24} 
          color={"white"} 
          style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 99, left: 0, top: 0}} />  
  </View>
```

**Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/rkHnZJrrH

Comment: Thanks. but zIndex might have issues when we move to different platforms